# Spring data, EclipseLink выборка определенных полей

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data

Есть 2 сущности с связью "многие-ко-многим", необходимо выбрать лишь определенные поля без инициализации остальных ("ленивая" инициализация включена)

```
@Entity
@NamedEntityGraph(
    name = "valueWithClassifiersSub",
    attributeNodes = {
        @NamedAttributeNode(value = "id"),
        @NamedAttributeNode(value = "value"),
        @NamedAttributeNode(value = "classifiers",subgraph = "classifiers")
    },
    subgraphs =
            @NamedSubgraph(
                name = "classifiers",
                attributeNodes =
                    @NamedAttributeNode(value = "id")
            )
)
@Table(name = "indicators_values")
public class IndicatorValue implements Serializable
```

Из следующей pojo необходимо выбрать лишь идентификаторы

```
@Entity
@NamedEntityGraph(
        name = "classifier.minimal",
        attributeNodes = {
            @NamedAttributeNode(value = "id"),
            @NamedAttributeNode(value = "name"),
            @NamedAttributeNode(value = "code"),
            @NamedAttributeNode(value = "classifierInfo",subgraph = "classifierInfo")
        },
        subgraphs = {
            @NamedSubgraph(
                    name = "classifierInfo",
                    attributeNodes = {
                            @NamedAttributeNode(value = "id"),
                            @NamedAttributeNode(value = "name"),
                            @NamedAttributeNode(value = "isConvolute"),
                            @NamedAttributeNode(value = "isDrillDowned")
                    }
            )
        }
)
@Table(name = "classifiers")
public class Classifier implements Serializable, Comparator<Classifier>
```

Репозиторий

```
@Repository
public interface IndicatorValuesRepo extends 

CrudRepository<IndicatorValue, Long> {
@EntityGraph(value = "valueWithClassifiersSub", type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.LOAD)
    @Query("select iv from IndicatorValue iv join fetch iv.classifiers cl "+
            "where iv.report.provider.form.id = :formId " +
            "   and iv.report.periodFinishDate = :finishDate " +
            "   and iv.indicator.id=:indId order by iv.report.periodFinishDate desc")
    List<IndicatorValue> getValuesByReportAndIndicator(@Param(value = "indId") Long indicatorId,
                                                       @Param(value = "finishDate") Date finishDate,
                                                       @Param(value = "formId") Long formId);
}
```

Но при вызове метода начинается инициализация других полей Classifier (аннотированных с Lazy)